# Managing screens of different size JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, screen, fxml

There is a blog by **Angela Caicedo** named [Managing Multiple Screens in JavaFX.](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1) which shows how to manage screens of **same size** and same background. However, if I want to manage screens with **different size**, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why does the size of screens impact the management of them?

Comment: @jewelsea Author managed all screens in one stage. So screen size is not dynamic. All screens must maintain the size of the stage.